# Input image source and instant show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following example, how can I make the image source variable and related to a text input, so that after tapping the image link it appear instantly without reloading the page?

```
<input style="text" name="img_link" placeholder="tape your image link" />

<img src="" />
```

Comment: Can you please be more explicit about the question?

Comment: Use `.change()` event to get value in input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign an event to your input, so that when it changes, update the `src` of the image.

There's a runnable snippet below. Any time you press a key in the input, or when the input loses focus, the image will automatically be updated.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").get(0).focus();
  $("input").on("blur keydown", function() {
    $("img").attr("src", $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input tyle="text" name="img_link" placeholder="tape your image link" value="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" />
<img src="" />
```